# Solr 4 Data Import Handler doesn't work

Tags: solr, log4j, dataimporthandler

I am deploying Solr 4.3.0 in Tomcat 7. 
Everything works fine but DataImportHandler. I can go to the

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/#/collection1/dataimport//dataimport
```

screen and see the dataimport options load at the UI.

Still, I can see any of my entities load in the "entity" combo box. Inside the configuration box, at the right side I can see the error below.

> Apache Tomcat/7.0.41 - Error
>   report
>
> ## 525D76;}--> HTTP Status 500 - Filter execution threw an exception
>
> noshade="noshade">
>
> **type** Exception report
>
> **message**
>   Filter execution threw an exception
>
> **description**
>   The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from
>   fulfilling this request.
>
> **exception**
>
> ```
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an
> exception
> ```
>
> **root cause**
>
> ```
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/spi/LoggingEvent
>   org.apache.solr.logging.log4j.EventAppender.append(EventAppender.java:35)
>   org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
>   org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
>   org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
>   org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
>   org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:856)
>   org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.error(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:498)
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException.log(SolrException.java:119)
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.ResponseUtils.getErrorInfo(ResponseUtils.java:58)
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.sendError(SolrDispatchFilter.java:691)
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:380)
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:155)
> ```
>
> **note** The full stack trace of the root cause is
>   available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.41 logs.
>
> #### Apache Tomcat/7.0.41

Problem is that I have the "log4j-1.2.16.jar" loaded in the classpath (it's on Tomcat lib dir).

Anyone have stepped in this problem?

Comment: Did you copy all the jars from the ext folder into the lib folder?

Comment: Yes, I did. This is how my Tomcat lib folder looks like:
`annotations-api.jar
catalina-ant.jar
catalina-ha.jar
catalina.jar
catalina-tribes.jar
ecj-4.2.2.jar
el-api.jar
jasper-el.jar
jasper.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar
jsp-api.jar
jul-to-slf4j-1.6.6.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
servlet-api.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar
tomcat-api.jar
tomcat-coyote.jar
tomcat-dbcp.jar
tomcat-i18n-es.jar
tomcat-i18n-fr.jar
tomcat-i18n-ja.jar
tomcat-jdbc.jar
tomcat-util.jar`

Comment: I just want to make sure after the making changes in configuration did you restart the tomcat and solr server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following the steps outlined in [Using the example logging setup in containers other than Jetty](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrLogging#Using_the_example_logging_setup_in_containers_other_than_Jetty). I have encountered this same error when running Solr 4.3 until I followed these steps to configure logging.

Comment: Thank you sir! That solved my problem. I have forgotten to put the log4j.properties file on my classpath. The error was not intuitive.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I wish the error were more helpful/meaningful towards pointing to where the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the `slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar` from the `ext` of `Solr` into the `lib` folder.

You also need to put the logging.properties file there.

Comment: Have you also placed the logging.properties file there?

Comment: That was the problem all the time. Thank you, sir.

Comment: I'll add it in the answer. Would be helpful for others too.

Answer (score 0):

After changing the directory, did you change the directory path in solrconfig.xml file.

I just want to make sure after the making changes in configuration file, did you restart the tomcat and solr server?